# Find $a$ if $y=f(x)$ satisfies $y-x\frac{dy}{dx} = a(y^2 +\frac{dy}{dx})$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> If the curve $y=f(x)$ satisfies the equation $y-x\frac{dy}{dx} = a(y^2 +\frac{dy}{dx})$ and always passes through $(1,1)$, then find number of possible values of $a$.

> Assume constant of integration to be 0

$$y-ay^2 =(a+x) \frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\ln (a+x) =\int a (\frac {1}{ay} + \frac{1}{1-ay})$$
$$a+x=\frac{y}{1-ay}$$

At $(1,1)$

$$(1+a)(1-a)=1$$
$$a=0$$

I could find one value of $a$, but the answer is 3. What are the other two?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy done

Comment: What does "always" mean in "the curve $y=f(x)$ ... *always* passes through $(1,1)$", to what manifold of cases does that refer, what would negate that expression?

Comment: Solving the DE I find $y=\frac{a+x}{a x+1}$. How can be found that possible values of $a$ are three???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful about zero appearing in the denominator. Also, the integral of $\frac  1 x$ is $\ln |x|$ not $\ln x$. Take $a+x=-\frac y {1-ay}$ to get another solution.  Two possible values of $a$ are $0$ and $1$ with solutions $y=x$ and $y=1$ respectively. For the third value put $x=y=1$ in $a+x=-\frac y {1-ay}$. This gives $a =\pm \sqrt 2$ but I will let you find out which one of these values is actually valid.

Comment: I don’t understand how you got $a=1$. There is $\pm$ value to the RHS, one gives $a=0$ and the other $a=\pm \sqrt 2$ for $x=y=1$

Comment: Also is $a=-\sqrt 2$ the correct answer?

Comment: Look at the case $\frac {dy} {dx}=0$. You will get $y=ay^{2}$. Together with the conidition $y=1$ when $x=1$ you get $a=1, y=1$ as  a solution. Yes, $-\sqrt 2$ is the third value. @Aditya

Comment: Why would you want $\frac{dy}{dx} =0$ The question doesn’t mention any such thing

Comment: In your first line there is a possibility of RHS being $0$ and your further steps are not valid in that case. You have to be exetremely careful with every step if you want to find all possoble values of $a$. @Aditya

Comment: That seems kinda arbitrary, doesn’t it? Why can’t we make LHS 0 and get $a=-1$? Is it because $y=1$?

Comment: @Aditya If you take RHS to be $0$ you will get $y=x$ as  the only solution. But for this $y$ what is the RHS? It can only be $0$ when $a=0$.

Comment: So would you consider this an ambiguous question, something which doesn’t have a definite answer?